# Merging branches leaves lines of code deleted

Tags: git

Suppose I have two branches A and B which is branched off from A.

Before merging A into B, some lines of code was removed from A.

When merging A into B, B ends up in a state that the change mentioned above does not reflect on B(so the removed lines of code still exits in B).

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: hang on... The removed lines stay? May you share the commands which show this issue? (Using fresh repos)

Comment: Merging is not about branches, but instead, is about commits and the commit graph. To explain why you get the result you are getting, we'd need to see the commit graph in this particular repository, and from that, the three file versions that are inputs to the merge operation.